# Can not use component using hooks inside redux modal

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a react redux app and the modal is managed through the redux store. So when user gets to the home page the `<Home />` and `<Modal />` mount at the root of the application. From there, whenever the user clicks a button that should open the modal, `displayModal` action is dispatched like so:

```
   const handleModalButtonClick = () => {
        this.props.actions.displayModal({
            className: 'modal-light',
            component: () => <FunctionalComponentThatUsesHooks />
        });
    };
```

The `<FunctionalComponentThatUsesHooks />` is what is supposed to open up in the modal. But this doesn't seem to work when the component passed is a component using hooks as I am seeing the invalid hooks call error:

`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:...`

The component using hooks is a function component, so I know that's not the issue. I can't seem to figure out exactly why this isn't working. Maybe has to do with the fact that the modal is managed  through the redux store or the way component is being passed? Any ideas? Thanks

update: the displayModal action has type `SHOW` which just just adds the data to the redux store as so:

```
   case SHOW:
            return {
                ...state,
                modal: action.payload
            };
```

in the `<Modal />`, using function `mapStateToProps` to get the `component` from the redux store. then the `<Modal />` render calls `this.modalBody` which will render that `component` from the redux store as so:

```
  get modalBody() {
        const {component: InnerComponent} = this.props;

        if (!InnerComponent) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <div className="modal-body"  ref={this.modalBodyNode}>
                <InnerComponent {...this.props} />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

the `<FunctionalComponentThatUsesHooks />` isn't any specific component, I've tried with multiple different components that use hooks, even simple ones that only use the `useState` hook like so:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const FunctionalComponentThatUsesHooks = (props) => {
    const [size] = useState(props.size);

    return (
      <button className={`btn-${size}`}>{props.children}</button>
    );
};

export default FunctionalComponentThatUsesHooks;
```

Comment: Show the minimal code about `FunctionalComponentThatUsesHooks` about how did you use hooks and show the code of `displayModal` method about how did you use the `component`

Comment: might have to do with the way I display the inner component in  the modalBody() ?

Comment: You still didn't put the code for FunctionalComponentThatUsesHooks

Comment: Sure, I've added above